# Vue: need to disable all inputs on page

Tags: vue.js, vue-directives

I'm developing an app that has different license types, and according to the license we need to disable/enable inputs.

One way is to put a conditional `:disabled` for each input but that's a lot of work and error prone, since we might forget to put it on some inputs.

I thought of using a directive like `v-disable-all` that searches for all inputs under the container and adds disabled to them.

I was wandering if there is a better solution or if there is already a solution like this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ended up creating this directive:

```
import Vue from "vue";

Vue.directive("disable-all", {
  // When all the children of the parent component have been updated
  componentUpdated: function(el, binding) {
    if (!binding.value) return;
    const tags = ["input", "button", "textarea", "select"];
    tags.forEach(tagName => {
      const nodes = el.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
      for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        nodes[i].disabled = true;
        nodes[i].tabIndex = -1;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: So pretty much what I said to do? Not sure why you didn’t just tick, but happy you got it sorted.

Comment: "I thought of using a directive like v-disable-all that searches for all inputs under the container and adds disabled to them." this is a quote from my question, and then i asked if there is another , better, way. you just told me to do what i wanted to do in the first place. Also you wrote it in simple JS and not as a Vue directive, so i gave you a thumbs up for the effort but you didn't really answer my question.

Answer (score 13):

I'am coming a bit late, but there is an attribute on the  HTML element called "disabled", which ... disable every input in the tree.

```
<fieldset :disabled="!canEdit">
  ...
</fieldset>
```

`canEdit` could be a computed property or anything you want.

Comment: Also hint: you can prevent `fieldset` from breaking your grid layout (for example) by setting `display: contents;` style to it.

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this:

`let elems = document.getElementById('parentDiv').getElementsByTagName('input');`

This will give you all the inputs inside a parent, then you can run a simple for loop to loop over them and set each one to disabled.

Something like this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].disabled = true;
}
```

Hope this helps set you on the right path.

```js
let elems = document.getElementById('someid').getElementsByTagName('input');

console.log(elems);

for(let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  elems[i].disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="someid">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: He could write a directive and append it to each input or the parent that does exactly as shown above. "One way is to put a conditional :disabled for each input but that's a lot of work and error prone, since we might forget to put it on some inputs." This covers all inputs inside a parent.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I'm aware of this solution, I was looking for a way to avoid it

Comment: You could write a watch function that has an array of licenses and the inputs that should be available when a license is selected and on change. But again, you would have to add each input to the array. I can't think of anything else off the top of my head.

Comment: Won't this stop working if anything on the model changes because Vue will regenerate the UI?

Comment: "input" selector doesn't account for SELECT tags

Answer (score 2):

Now you just need to wrap your fields inside `<v-form :disabled="variable"></v-form>`

Comment: v-form is not a Vuejs directive, but Vuetify component.

Comment: @Elmatou you are right. My bad! Is because I got used to Vuetify(my question, why would you not use Vuetify??)

Comment: Because you use Buefy ! just a matter of CSS framework

Comment: I can ensure you is not just a matter of CSS ;)

Comment: @pabloRN While this is not the correct answer to OP, it was the perfect solution for me since I use Vuetify too. Thanks!